# Calculating the support for the CDF: $Y = X^2, X \geq 0$ and $- 2X, X < 0$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to understand how to determine the limits of the integral for calculating the cdf of a fairly simple transformation, but struggling conceptually to understand the support.

Would it be accurate to say the integral when calculating the cdf, goes from $-\infty$ to $0$ ? If so, isn't the transformation divergent? How do you determine the cdf in such cases? Does the cdf just not exist?

Comment: there has to be more to this problem

Comment: The full problem was Y is $X^2$ if X ≥ 0, and −2X if X<0. The CDF of Y when X is positive is just a square transformation, if I am not mistaken? I got the CDF for that part as $F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X (-\sqrt{y})$ and the pdf as $\frac{1}{(2 \sqrt{y})} (f_X(\sqrt{y})) + \frac{1}{(2 \sqrt{y})} f_X (-\sqrt{y})$

Comment: @newmathlearner_7 Include all relevant info in your original post by clicking on 'edit'.

Comment: I have changed the question title to include the full question and follow the reasons for the answer; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $X \in \mathbb R$, that is to say, the support of $X$ is the set of all real numbers, then the support of $Y$ is found by considering how $$Y = \begin{cases} X^2, & X \ge 0 \\ -2X, & X < 0 \end{cases}$$ maps each of the intervals $[0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ under this transformation.  In the first case, clearly $X^2 \ge 0$ when $X \ge 0$, thus $Y \ge 0$.  In the second, when $X < 0$, then $-2X > 0$, consequently, $Y > 0$.  It follows that the support of $Y$ is the interval $[0, \infty)$.